# Concurrent program execution failing if it is executed by French user

Tags: sql, oracle

We developed one procedure which will extract data for Fixed asset projection and create .csv output. We registered concurrent program in Oracle application. We came to know that when US or UK business users executes this program its working fine, but French user execute this program it will complete with Error.

When I checked in log file I can see program execution is failing while creating listagg function.

```
 select listagg('''' || TO_CHAR(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YY') || ''' as "' || TO_CHAR(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YY') || '"', ',') within group (order by PERIOD_NAME)
  into   pivot_clause
  from   (select   TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') PERIOD_NAME from FA_PROJ_INTERIM_RPT where request_id = p_req_id
  GROUP BY TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') order by TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') ASC);
```

Comment: What contains PERIOD_NAME ? April is APR for English,  AVR for French...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question using the `edit` button just below the question tags and include information about the error which occurs. Thanks.

Comment: Period name contains, APR-19
AUG-19
DEC-19
FEB-20
JAN-20

Comment: @LucM Period name contains, APR-19 AUG-19 DEC-19 FEB-20 JAN-20

Comment: *"it will complete with Error"* What error do you see in the log file? Please give us all the information you have, so we don't have to guess the problem.

Comment: Please update the question with a [MCVE] including the full error message, the full code of the procedure, some sample data that replicates the problems and the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter of the working and non-working environments. We can guess and propose solutions but if you provide the full details you will get a much better response and we may even be able to eliminate the dynamic pivot you are building.

Answer (score 2):

First, I agree with Luc M that it would be better to change your data model to use an ISO 8601 format, and avoid naming months.  But I understand that changing the model is not always an option.

If the data must be kept in English, but converted by non-English sessions, you can set an explicit NLSPARAM in the `TO_DATE` function to ensure that the conversion always happens in English.  If not set, NLSPARAM will use the session default.

For example, I believe this test reproduces your problem:

```
--Returns: 2019-04-01
alter session set nls_language = 'AMERICAN';
select to_date('APR-2019', 'MON-YYYY') the_date from dual;

--Fails with: ORA-01843: ce n'est pas un mois valide
alter session set nls_language = 'CANADIAN FRENCH';
select to_date('APR-2019', 'MON-YYYY') the_date from dual;
```

This is the code to fix it:

```
--Returns: 2019-04-01
alter session set nls_language = 'AMERICAN';
select to_date('APR-2019', 'MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') the_date from dual;

--Returns: 2019-04-01
alter session set nls_language = 'FRENCH';
select to_date('APR-2019', 'MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') the_date from dual;
```

Internationalization is hard.  It wouldn't surprise me if there's still another bug in my above code, maybe for a different calendar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you try to convert to a DATE that is not a date in French.

To make it work, you have 2 options.

Remove TO_CHAR and TO_DATE from your query.

```
  select listagg('''' || PERIOD_NAME || ''' as "' || PERIOD_NAME || '"', ',')   
  within group (order by PERIOD_NAME)
  into   pivot_clause
  from   (select PERIOD_NAME as PERIOD_NAME 
          from FA_PROJ_INTERIM_RPT 
          where request_id = p_req_id
          GROUP BY PERIOD_NAME
          order by PERIOD_NAME ASC
        );
```

Translate the month abbreviation to French  (you have to code it...)

```
JAN --> JAN  
FEB --> FEV  
MAR --> MAR  
APR --> AVR  
MAY --> MAI  
JUN --> JUN  
JUL --> JUI  
AUG --> AOU  
SEP --> SEP  
OCT --> OCT  
NOV --> NOV  
DEC --> DEC
```

From the start, PERIOD_NAME should have been 2019-01 for January 2019.

It's easier to sort, no translation needed.

**EDIT**

The suitable solution for your problem as Jon Heller explained is to modify on the fly the NLS_LANGUAGE value.

But I would suggest you to reset it to the original language after executing your query to avoid problems elsewhere

```
original_language := userenv( 'LANG' );

-- I suppose by French you mean French Canadian...
IF original_language = 'FRC' THEN 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN';
END IF;

-- execute your query here

IF original_language = 'FRC' THEN 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE=CANADIAN FRENCH';
END IF;
```

The code has not been tested. I wrote some lines as example because I think it's better than explanations.

Comment: We are getting period name from FA_PROJ_INTERIM_RPT after providing request id. When I checked in FA_PROJ_INTERIM_RPT in period_name column, I can see periods are with UK calendar i.e JAN 
FEB 
MAR 
APR 
MAY 
JUN
JUL 
AUG 
SEP 
OCT 
NOV 
DEC

Comment: @prashantkulkarni - *"Period name contains, APR-19 AUG-19 DEC-19 FEB-20 JAN-20."* So the instruction `TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY')` will be a problem if your French users are running with `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=FRENCH` set in their client environments.

Comment: Thanks Luc and Jon for your advice. Once program execution completes do I need to reset NLS_LANGUAGE?